# python plot simple histogram given binned data

Tags: python, plot, matplotlib, histogram

I have count data (a 100 of them), each correspond to a bin (0 to 99). I need to plot these data as histogram. However, histogram count those data and does not plot correctly because my data is already binned.

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = random.sample(range(1000), 100)
xbins = [0, len(x)]
#plt.hist(x, bins=xbins, color = 'blue') 
#Does not make the histogram correct. It counts the occurances of the individual counts. 

plt.plot(x)
#plot works but I need this in histogram format
plt.show()
```

Comment: You could use the code in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37559471/2087463) or this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37548733/2087463) as an example for plotting already binned data as histograms.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you want to achieve correctly then the following should give you what you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(range(0,100), x)
plt.show()
```

It doesn't use `hist()`, but it looks like you've already put your data into bins so there's no need.

Comment: If you want the `bar` to look more like the `hist` output use the code in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37559471/2087463) or this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37548733/2087463) as an example for plotting histograms via the `bar` plot.

Answer (score 12):

The problem is with your xbins. You currently have

```
xbins = [0, len(x)]
```

which will give you the list [0, 100]. This means you will only see 1 bin (not 2) bounded below by 0 and above by 100. I am not totally sure what you want from your histogram. If you want to have 2 unevenly spaced bins, you can use

```
xbins = [0, 100, 1000]
```

to show everything below 100 in one bin, and everything else in the other bin. Another option would be to use an integer value to get a certain number of evenly spaced bins. In other words do

```
plt.hist(x, bins=50, color='blue')
```

where bins is the number of desired bins.

On a side note, whenever I can't remember how to do something with matplotlib, I will usually just go to the [thumbnail gallery](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) and find an example that looks more or less what I am trying to accomplish. These examples all have accompanying source code so they are quite helpful. The [documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) for matplotlib can also be very handy.

Answer (score 7):

Cool, thanks!  Here's what I think the OP wanted to do:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[x/1000 for x in random.sample(range(100000),100)]
xbins=range(0,len(x))
plt.hist(x, bins=xbins, color='blue')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly sure that your problem is the bins. It is not a list of limits but rather a list of bin edges.

```
xbins = [0,len(x)]
```

returns in your case a list containing `[0, 100]` Indicating that you want a bin edge at 0 and one at 100. So you get one bin from 0 to 100.
What you want is:

```
xbins = [x for x in range(len(x))]
```

Which returns:

```
[0,1,2,3, ... 99]
```

Which indicates the bin edges you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using matplotlib's hist as well, no need for numpy. You have essentially already created the bins as `xbins`. In this case `x` will be your weights.

```
plt.hist(xbins,weights=x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the histogram [examples](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html) in the matplotlib documentation. You should use the [`hist`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) function. If it by default does not yield the result you expect, then play around with the arguments to `hist` and prepare/transform/modify your data before providing it to `hist`. It is not really clear to me what you want to achieve, so I cannot help at this point.

Comment: after trying for a while I asked this question. My only concern is if I can achieve what the above code does with hist function.